# ¿Método para rotar una imagen BMP en c?

Tags: c, bitmap

Estoy creando un metodo que me rote una imagen BMP 90 grados, pero no me rota la imagen como quiero

Adjunto la imagen que estoy usando

[image: Esta es la imagen que estoy usando]

El método que aplico para rotarla es el siguiente

```
void rotar(BMP *img){
int i,j;
for(i=0; i < img->alto; i++){
    for(j=0; j < img->ancho; j++){

    img->pixelR[j][i] = img->pixelR[i][j];  
    img->pixelG[j][i] = img->pixelG[i][j];
    img->pixelB[j][i] = img->pixelB[i][j];

    }
 }

}
```

Y el resultado no es el esperado

[image: Resultado de la aplicacion del metodo]

Me gustaría que me dijeran que estoy haciendo mal, llevo días atascado aquí. Como dato extra si yo le paso como parametro una imagen BMP de un largo y ancho diferente no me guarda la imagen, también me gustaría poder hacer que el método rote imagenes sin importar que tanto tenga de largo y ancho.
De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás sobreescribiendo parte de la imagen. Antes de hacer esto:

```
img->pixelR[j][i] = img->pixelR[i][j];  
img->pixelG[j][i] = img->pixelG[i][j];
img->pixelB[j][i] = img->pixelB[i][j];
```

Tienes que haber hecho una copia de `img->pixelR[j][i]`, `img->pixelG[j][i]` y `img->pixelB[j][i]`. Si no lo haces los valores que se encontraban ahí se perderán irremediablemente.

Así pues lo primero que tienes que hacer es una copia completa del mapa de bits, tras esto rotas la imagen tomando los datos de la copia y sobreescribiendo el original y, finalmente, te queda liberar la memoria asociada a la copia:

```
void rotar(BMP *img){
  BMP* copia = CopiarBmp(img);

  int i,j;
  for(i=0; i < img->alto; i++){
    for(j=0; j < img->ancho; j++){
      img->pixelR[j][i] = copia->pixelR[i][j];  
      img->pixelG[j][i] = copia->pixelG[i][j];
      img->pixelB[j][i] = copia->pixelB[i][j];
    }
  }

  LiberarBmp(copia);
}
```

Comment: oh entiendo, necesito una copia de donde sacar los datos del bmp original para modificar el bmp original, ahora vere la forma de copiar el bmp y liberar la copia de bmp, ¡muchas gracias por responder!