# Como rotar 90° una imagen en c++

Tags: c++

En este codigo, se reciben dos parametros. Una lista bidimensional que contendra una matriz de una imagen y un vector que sera la copia de esta. Estan asi para que pueda tomar valores de la copia y modificarlos en la original sin alterar los valores. El codigo que intente para rotar la imagen fue el siguiente:

```
                  void ImageTools::mirror(Image *picture, ImageVector original){
                  vector<vector<int>> originalImg = original.getVector();
                  for (int i = 0; i < originalImg.size(); i++)
                  {
                    for (int j = 0; j < originalImg[i].size(); j++)
                    {

                      int r = originalImg[i][j];
                      int g = originalImg[i][j + 1];
                      int b = originalImg[i][j + 2];

                      picture->setPixel(i, j, b);
                      picture->setPixel(i, j + 1, g);
                      picture->setPixel(i, j + 2, r);

                      j = j + 2;
                    }
                  }

                  }
```

Donde en la matriz, existe el R G B, y para rotarlo decido que tenga la forma B G R, pero solo me cambio la gama de colores a uno mas verdoso, que se necesitaria para rotar la imagen a 90°?

Comment: Hola, este codigo lo tengo hecho pero en c#, dime si te interesaría al menos para llevarte una idea de cómo se hace

Comment: Hola, si por favor, o si puedes explicarme la logica que se haría.

Comment: Dime en qué ide estás trabajando, visualstudio?

Comment: En repl.it, pero aveces trabajo en vs

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/199878/m%C3%A9todo-para-rotar-una-imagen-bmp-en-c entra aqui

Comment: Hola, por fin resolviste